# What's the name of the forest the Quidditch World Cup is held in?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, the Ministry of Magic constructs a massive stadium in a forest to hold the Quidditch World Cup. Is the name of the forest ever mentioned?

Possibly it's one of the places Hermione apparates the trio back there at some point in the seventh book?

Comment: I don't believe this is ever mentioned; apparently the film is set in Dartmoor, but I don't think it gets any more specific than that

Comment: It is in fact the first woods Hermione apparates them to (immediately after the incident at the ministry), but she just says "In the woods where they held the Quidditch World Cup," no specific name.

Comment: The only woods that were specifically named in the books was the Forest of Dean (West Gloucestershire) near where JK Rowling went to school (and I live).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the official HP wiki:

> The Quidditch Trillenium Stadium[1], known also as the Quidditch World Cup Stadium[2] was built for the 422nd Quidditch World Cup in 1994. Built in the middle of a large deserted moor in Dartmoor, the Quidditch stadium was capable of holding 100,000 wizards at once, with halls draped in scarlet.

But about the campsite in the movie:

> For the film adaptation of Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, scenes at the Quidditch World Cup Campsite were filmed at Beachy Head, in Eastbourne, East Sussex. Beachy Head is known for its chalk sea cliffs, which are seen on the film. While the novel does not specify where the campsite was located, exactly, later, Pottermore revealed it was in Dartmoor, which is actually landlocked.

Comment: Appreciate this answer. Any guesses as to where in Dartmoor seems most likely would still be welcome!

Comment: In 1994, the 422nd Quidditch World Cup was held in a "nice deserted moor" in Dartmoor. from the wiki

Comment: FYI: There is no "official" HP wiki. It's just a bunch of random people editing articles.